# How to add a rewrite endpoint to unattached media?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, endpoints

I'm trying to add an endpoint to unattached media items. This is what I hope to achieve:

example.com/attachment-slug/foo/

...where `foo` is the endpoint I'm trying to add.

Here's my code:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'foo', EP_ATTACHMENT );
} );

add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    global $wp_query;
    if ( ! isset( $wp_query->query_vars['foo'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/my-template.php';
    exit;
} );
```

This doesn't seem to work because when I visit example.com/attachment-slug/foo/ I get a 404.

How can I add an endpoint to unattached media?

Comment: Using 'include' and then 'exit' seems problematic.  Have you read this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect#Loading_a_different_template

Comment: Hi @shanebp, I copied that from here https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/. Didn't think to double check it. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EP_ATTACHMENT` will insert rules for things attached to posts (and custom post types), but not unattached media.

You can make this work by adding it to `EP_PAGES` instead-

```
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'foo', EP_PAGES );
```